# Ruby on Rails rich many:many, using a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, has-many-through

I have an existing database I'm trying to map to Ruby on Rails ActiveRecords. One of the tables is a 'rich join' table that has pre-calculated distances between zip codes and airports. The 'zipcode' (char) column is the primary key for the zipcode database table. The table definitions are below.

Right now I have the following Rails models (they're working insofar as I can retrieve all the airports linked to a ZIP code):

zipcode.rb:

```
class Zipcode < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :zipcode_airports, :foreign_key => :zipcode
    has_many :airports, :through => :zipcode_airports
end
```

zipcode_airport.rb

```
class ZipcodeAirport < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "airport_zip_distances"
    belongs_to :zipcode, :foreign_key => :zipcode
    belongs_to :airport
end
```

So  this works:

```
irb(main):001:0> z = Zipcode.find("90210")
   Zipcode Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `zipcodes`.* FROM `zipcodes` WHERE `zipcodes`.`zipcode` = '90210' LIMIT 1
=> #<Zipcode zipcode: "90210", latitude: 34.0901, longitude: -118.406>
```

As does this:

```
irb(main):002:0> z.airports
  Airport Load (738.4ms)  SELECT `airports`.* FROM `airports` INNER JOIN `airport_zip_distances` ON `airports`.`airport_id` = `airport_zip_distances`.`airport_id` WHERE `airport_zip_distances`.`zipcode` = '90210'
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Airport airport_id: 11, name: "RIO VISTA MUNI", latitude: 38.1933, longitude: -121.704>, #<Airport airport_id: 12, name: "MARBLE CANYON", latitude: 36.8108, longitude: -111.645>, #<Airport airport_id: 13, name: "MONTEREY RGNL", latitude: 36.587, longitude: -121.843>, #<Airport airport_id: 14, name: "HOOPA", latitude: 41.0415, longitude: -123.668>, #<Airport airport_id: 15, name: "LEACH", latitude: 37.785, longitude: -106.047>, #<Airport airport_id: 16, name: "MANTI–EPHRAIM", latitude: 39.3315, longitude: -111.613>, #<Airport airport_id: 17, name: "MEADOWS FLD", latitude: 35.4338, longitude: -119.058>, #<Airport airport_id: 18, name: "GRAVELLY VALLEY", latitude: 39.4507, longitude: -122.955>, #<Airport airport_id: 19, name: "GUSTINE", latitude: 37.2605, longitude: -120.964>, #<Airport airport_id: 20, name: "CALIFORNIA PINES", latitude: 41.4122, longitude: -120.684>, ...]>
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to limit the records returned to those where, e.g., airport_zip_distances.distance_in_miles < 7 miles.

This query works, I'm just not sure how to get everything setup properly in Rails to get it to formulate it:

```
mysql> SELECT `airports`.* FROM `airports` INNER JOIN `airport_zip_distances` ON `airports`.`airport_id` = `airport_zip_distances`.`airport_id` WHERE `airport_zip_distances`.`zipcode` = '90210' AND `airport_zip_distances`.`distance_in_miles` < 7;
+------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+
| airport_id | name              | latitude | longitude |
+------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+
|         37 | SANTA MONICA MUNI |  34.0158 |  -118.451 |
+------------+-------------------+----------+-----------+
```

Here's the database table layout, if it matters...

```
mysql> describe airports;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| airport_id | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| latitude   | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| longitude  | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe zipcodes;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| zipcode   | char(5) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| latitude  | float   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| longitude | float   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> describe airport_zip_distances;
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| airport_id        | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| zipcode           | char(5) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| distance_in_miles | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Help?! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is simply if we define some scopes in `Airport` like this:

```
class Airport < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_zipcode, -> (zipcode) { where(zipcode: zipcode) }
  scope :in_distance, -> (miles) {
    joins(:airport_zip_distances).where('airport_zip_distances.distance_in_miles < ?', miles)
}
end
```

After that, we can:

1. Find the airports with zipcode

   ```
   Airport.with_zipcode(12345)
   ```
2. Find the airports with distance

   ```
   Airport.in_distance(5)
   ```
3. Find the airports with zipcode & distance

   ```
   Airport.with_zipcode(12345).in_distance(5)
   ```